# Can not start IntelliJ IDEA by Clicking ICON from Launch bar on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have version of ubuntu 13.10 running on my PC, I have recently shifted from windows to linux ubuntu, I have installed intellJ IDEA with full configuration set, and I have been using it for two weeks now.

The problem I am facing from day 1 is that I have IntelliJ IDEA Icon in the launch bar, but clicking on the icon does not opens/runs it.

I have to write the following command in the terminal to run intelliJ IDEA.

`muhammad@raees-pc:~$ cd /home/muhammad/IDEA/idea-IU-133.696/bin`
`muhammad@raees-pc:~/IDEA/idea-IU-133.696/bin$ ./idea.sh`

Although it is working fine, but why not it opens on click by mouse,
I any one had same problem found solution please share with me,

Comment: What does your shortcut in the launch bar point to?

Comment: Well then there's your problem :) make it launch `idea.sh`

Comment: I am doing so by command terminal. I wished i could get a solution to start it by click.

Comment: What I meant was make your shortcut/icon from launch bar, run the `idea.sh` startup script. Maybe this will be more explicit http://nufailm.blogspot.ro/2012/05/custom-launcher-for-intellij-idea-in.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file `intilliJ.desktop`, input the content as fellows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Comment=IntelliJ IDEA IDE
Exec=/home/nufail/apps/idea-IC-107.587/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/home/nufail/apps/idea-IC-107.587/bin/idea_CE128.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

Then move the file to `~/.local/share/applications`. If you want all users can use this application, you can add this file to `/usr/share/applications/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
First method you can  restore it and choose start icon something like in my memory.
Also  you can try delete the icon ,start from shell idea.sh ,and then right click add lock from start.
My english is not good. hope you can understand me and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

it should be enough to change the command of icon (RMB -> Properties) so that it points to idea.sh, as @Morfic said but only in a comment.